# How to use OPENJSON if column is same in SQL?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, open-json

My database table is created as :

```
declare @library table (dependencies varchar(max))

insert into @library values('{"jar":"azure.com","maven":"azure.com","maven":"azure.com","maven":"azurebook.com"}')
```

I am trying to have JSON as

```
{
 "libraries":[
    {
      "jar" : { "coordinates":"azure.com"}
    },
    {
      "maven" : {"coordinates":"azure.com" }
    },
    {
      "maven" : {"coordinates":"azurebook.com" }
    }
 ]
}
```

And my SQL code looks like

```
SELECT
  (
      select
        j.jar as [jar.coordinates],
        j.maven as [maven.coordinates]
      FROM OPENJSON(l.dependencies)
        WITH (
          jar varchar(100),
          maven varchar(100)
        ) j
      FOR JSON PATH
  ) as libraries
  
FROM @library l
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

And my output which is not same as desired json

```
 {
 "libraries":[
    {
      "jar" : { "coordinates":"azure.com"}
    },
    {
      "maven" : {"coordinates":"azure.com" }
    }
 ]
}
```

As in my output, my other property or column **maven** does not including.
Can somebody help me out?

Thank you

Comment: Sample data will help us help you.

Comment: @Larnu , I have edited, can you check

Comment: Do ensure that's *really* your input and it cannot be changed on the producing end, because duplicate property names are a bad idea (the standard doesn't outright forbid it, but notes the behavior of implementations on receiving it is not consistent). You'd normally expect an array of values, as per your output, but not your input. This would typically indicate a fault in the process generating this output (it could easily happen if the output is manually generated rather than serialized, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this using `OPENJSON` with a schema, because JSON normally expects only unique property names. You can use `OPENJSON` without a schema, but you also cannot use `FOR JSON` to create such a JSON value. You would need `STRING_AGG` again

```sql
SELECT
  JSON_QUERY((
      SELECT
        '[' + STRING_AGG(
          '{"' +
          STRING_ESCAPE(j.[key], 'json') +
          '":"' +
          STRING_ESCAPE(j.value, 'json') +
          '"}',
          ','
        ) + ']'
      FROM OPENJSON(l.dependencies) j
  )) as libraries
FROM @library l
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0f88f3576aadee483e3d6a554390706f)

Comment: If I have null , so It is not working. Then what should we do ? i want to make it more generic

Comment: You can use `CONCAT` instead, which ignores nulls

Comment: But If values are null, then i don't that property to include in my JSON. Like I tested, with null values, It is not property null. But I don't want that property in json if null

Comment: OK then use the original `+`, it works fine for me? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=28e68dd5bd47130937cdbca589566369 Can you construct a fiddle showing it not working and showing what you would like to see

Comment: Okay got it. Its working now